# How to change reference number after adding rows?

Tags: google-sheets, scripting, google-sheets-macros

I have tried to record a macro to change the numbers in a column after adding data.
*1070
1071
144
145
146*
The *144..146* has been added and I want to change them to 1072 .. 1074 with a macro.

Here is my recorded macro with the addition of range

```
function newcolumnnumbers() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 2, 1).activate();
var destinationRange = spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(range, 0,0);
spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(destinationRange, 
SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
// spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0,range, 1).activate();
};
```

Unfortunately the macro does not stop at the last filled cell but continues to the bottom of the sheet.  What have I done wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is this about [google-sheets] / [google-apps-script] ? May get better audience if tagged appropriately

Comment: I am using Google sheets. scripts.  i don't know the difference you list.  Sorry.  How do I add the tag as you suggest?

Comment: You edit your post and add the relevant tag(s) alongside "scripting" (see "Tags" at the bottom of the form).